# return value of a Cell if another cell is matched in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Hi I am trying to get a small list of user names and match it with a global list of usernames and emails and output their emails if a match is found.

Columns A and B have the global user name and email address
Colomn C has my small list of usernames .
column D shows true if Column C is found in column A
I need a formula that outputs the email(column B) of the match between column C and column A

This is my current formula for the matching that is working perfectly( Column D).

```
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH($C3,$A$2:$A$99504,0)))
```

I just need the email of that match for column E

***Example***

Abauats  |  email@email.com | abbee  |TRUE  | email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a `VLOOKUP` in cell E2 and copied down as per below.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")
```

Regards,